# refactoring JS files in React

Tags: reactjs

I am repeating this code is a few components and I find it repetitive:

```
componentDidMount(){        
        let scripts = [
            {src:"/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"},
            {src:"/lib/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js"},
            {src:"/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"},
            {src:"/lib/easing/easing.min.js"},
            {src:"/lib/superfish/hoverIntent.js"},
            {src:"/lib/superfish/superfish.min.js"},
            {src:"/lib/wow/wow.min.js"},
            {src:"/lib/waypoints/waypoints.min.js"},
            {src:"/lib/counterup/counterup.min.js"},
            {src:"/lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"},
            {src:"/lib/isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js"},
            {src:"/lib/lightbox/js/lightbox.min.js"},
            {src:"/lib/touchSwipe/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"},
            {src:"/lib/main.js"},
            {src:"/contactform/contactform.js"}           
            
        ]
        //Append the script element on each iteration
        scripts.map(item => { 
            const script = document.createElement("script")
            script.src = item.src
            script.async = false
            script.defer = false
            document.body.appendChild(script)
        })  
    }
```

I am not sure how I can put all this into one JS file so that I could just use the import statement.

Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciated,

Comment: why not importing them using *static import*s ?

Comment: Maybe create a react hook but since you are using class components you won't be able to them.

Comment: I did try the static import but the issues it does not load all the time and that affects the page like isotope.pkgd.min.js. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Put these scripts in the root of your app. Use [react-inline-script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-inline-script) to avoid manually manipulating the DOM yourself.

Or

- Install the npm packages for the scripts you need (when available) and import the module you need using ES6 imports.